# Problemas com o retorno do relacionamente hasMany

Tags: laravel-5

Estou trabalhando na tabela de Lote de meu projeto onde cada lote terá seu único produto e cada produto poderá ter vários lotes. Montei todo o relacionamento e agora estou testando o acesso pelos `métodos`. ao fazer `$produto->lotes` consigo obter resposta satisfatória porém ao fazer `$lotes->produto` não está conseguindo retorna nada.

Meu `controller` está da seguinte maneira:

```
 public function mostrar($id){
    $lotes =  LoteProduto::where('CdProduto', $id)->get();

    dd($lotes->produto);

    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return $lotes;
    }else{
        return view('LoteProduto.listLoteProduto', compact('lotes'));
    }
}
```

Na minha pesquisa de lotes ja tentei estas possibilidades:

```
$lotes =  LoteProduto::where('CdProduto', $id)->first();
$lotes =  LoteProduto::where('CdProduto', $id)->get()->first();
$lotes =  LoteProduto::where('CdProduto', $id)->get()->item;
```

Em meu `model Produto` tenho a `função`:

```
public function lotes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\LoteProduto', 'CdProduto', 'CdProduto');
}
```

que me retorna perfeitamente os lotes.

Ja em meu `model Lote` tenho:

```
class LoteProduto extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'CdProduto',
        'DtFrabricacao',
        'DtValidade',
        'QtdUnitProduzida'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'CdLote';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function produto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Produto','CdProduto','CdProduto');
    }

}
```

Quando tento acessar o `$lotes->produto` o seguinte erro é mostrado na tela:

> ErrorException in LoteProdutoController.php line 25: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$produto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que carregar o relacionamento:

```
$lotes  = LoteProduto::with('produto')->where('CdProduto', $id)->get();
foreach($lotes as $lote):
    $lote->produto ...
endforeach;
```

e isso retorna uma lista, tem que percorrer com `for`.

Comment: Mas e para acessar como faço ?

Comment: Fiz isto $lotes->produto = Produto::find($id); porém la na página ele identifica que ja tem lotes criados e não tem

Comment: Olha o erro que deu Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$produto (View: C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\PROJETOS\SGLE-Padaria\resources\views\LoteProduto\listLoteProduto.blade.php)

Comment: Alterei era outra coisa

Comment: Ainda sim esta dando problema

Comment: Coloque o model LoteProduto!

Comment: editei a pergunta

Comment: Da um var_dump nessa variável lotes e cole na questão e outra será que tem dados????

Comment: Tem também problema não deveria ser muito pra muitos???

Comment: Não, justamente o problema acontece por isto, pois não tenho nenhum lote, quando tenho lote vai normal

Comment: Não, cada produto tem seu lote

Comment: ou melhor cada lote tem seu produto e cada produto tem seus lotes

Comment: Dentro de um lote tem quantos produtos? E um produto pode estar em vários lotes?

Comment: Dentro de um lote, existe apenas um produto, e dentro de um produto pode ter varios lotes

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45830/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-renan-rodrigues).

Comment: É que retorna uma lista precisa de um for ali

Comment: O comando deveria ser dd($lotes)